# No OpenCL devices found in your system. Closing lolMiner

Tags: mining

New to mining. I am trying to figure out how to use lolMiner on Ubuntu 20.04. Here are the specs of my GPU:

```
*-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Ellesmere [Radeon RX 470/480/570/570X/580/580X/590]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
       version: ef
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=amdgpu latency=0
       resources: irq:62 memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f01fffff ioport:e000(size=256) memory:fcf00000-fcf3ffff memory:c0000-dffff
```

When I try to enter into lolMiner, I get this error:

```
+---------------------------------------------------------+
|  _       _ __  __ _                   _   ____  ____    |
| | | ___ | |  \/  (_)_ __   ___ _ __  / | |___ \| ___|   |
| | |/ _ \| | |\/| | | '_ \ / _ \ '__| | |   __) |___ \   |
| | | (_) | | |  | | | | | |  __/ |    | |_ / __/ ___) |  |
| |_|\___/|_|_|  |_|_|_| |_|\___|_|    |_(_)_____|____/   |
|                                                         |
|              This software is for mining                |
|              Ethash, Etchash                            |
|              Equihash 144/5, 192/7, 210/9               |
|              BeamHash I, II, III                        |
|              ZelHash     (EquihashR 125/4/0)            |
|              Cuck(ar)oo 29                              |
|              Cuckaroo   30 CTX                          |
|              Cuckatoo   31/32                           |
|                                                         |
|                                                         |
|             Made by Lolliedieb, April 2021              |
+---------------------------------------------------------+

Setup Miner... 
No OpenCL devices found in your system. Closing lolMiner.
```

Does using lolMiner or any miner for that matter not allow you to use any Radeon RX GPUs?

I tried finding resources to help me but I am diving into rabbit holes with not getting anywhere with figuring it out.